# How to create a coloured table usig multirow and rotated text?

Tags: tables, spacing, vertical-alignment, multirow, colortbl

If someone look for mine today's question, is all about a table. Despites the important tips that I received, I still don't know how to create my table. So I decided to show an image of what I exactly want, and what I have

This is the table that I want:

[image]

This is actually what I have in LaTeX

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{55,171,200}
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{113,200,55}
\definecolor{pool}{RGB}{85,221,255}
\begin{document}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{c|*4{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}}

& \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text} \\
\hline
\parbox[c]{10pt}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Text}\end{sideways}}  & \multirow{2}{3cm}{\centering\cellcolor{darkblue}Three\\Lines\\Text} & \multirow{2}{3cm}{\cellcolor{darkblue}\centering Three\\Lines\\Text} & & \\
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-5}
\parbox[c]{10pt}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Text}\end{sideways}} &\cellcolor{darkblue} &\cellcolor{darkblue} & \cellcolor{darkblue}\shortstack[c]{Three\\Lines\\Text} & \\
\hline
\parbox[c]{10pt}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Text}\end{sideways}} & \cellcolor{green}\shortstack[c]{Three\\Lines\\Text} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cellcolor{pool}Single line text}\\
\hline
\parbox[c]{10pt}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Text}\end{sideways}} & \cellcolor{darkblue} \shortstack[c]{Two Lines\\Text} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cellcolor{pool}Single line text}\\
\hline
\parbox[c]{10pt}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Text}\end{sideways}} & \cellcolor{green}\shortstack[c]{Three\\Lines\\Text} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cellcolor{pool}Single line text}\\
\hline
\parbox[c]{10pt}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Text}\end{sideways}} & \cellcolor{darkblue} \shortstack[c]{two Lines\\Text} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cellcolor{pool} single line text} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general is not a good idea mix `colortbl` with `multirow` and the same apply to table rules, specially with those of `booktabs`. Sometimes could be a tricky way to fit things, but anyway my suggestion is redesign the table.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[12pt,margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{55,171,200}
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{113,200,55}
\definecolor{pool}{RGB}{85,221,255}
\begin{document}
\footnotesize

\setlength\arrayrulewidth{-1pt}
\setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}
\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
\setlength\fboxsep{-1pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{4}
\colorbox{darkblue}{%
\begin{tabular}{|>{\cellcolor{white}}c*4{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}|}}\\[-7em]
\rowcolor{white}& \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text} \\
\cmidrule{1-5}
\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{\textbf{Text}} & \multirow{2}{3cm}{\centering Three\\Lines\\Text} & \multirow{2}{3cm}{\centering Three\\Lines\\Text} &\cellcolor{white} &\cellcolor{white} \\
\cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{4-5}
\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{\textbf{Text}} &  & & \shortstack[c]{Three\\Lines\\Text} &\cellcolor{white} \\
\cmidrule{1-5}
\rotatebox[origin=b]{45}{\textbf{Text}} & \cellcolor{green}\shortstack[c]{Three\\Lines\\Text} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cellcolor{pool}Single line text}\\
\cmidrule{1-5}
\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{\textbf{Text}} & \cellcolor{darkblue} \shortstack[c]{Two Lines\\Text} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cellcolor{pool}Single line text}\\
\cmidrule{1-5}
\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{\textbf{Text}} & \cellcolor{green}\shortstack[c]{Three\\Lines\\Text} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cellcolor{pool}Single line text}\\
\cmidrule{1-5}
\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{\textbf{Text}} & \cellcolor{darkblue} \shortstack[c]{two Lines\\Text} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cellcolor{pool} single line text} \\
\midrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution. The trick for the `multirow text` not being hidden by the coloured background is to insert the `\multirow` command in the last row, with a negative argument. I took the opportunity to simplify your code.

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow, bigstrut, cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{3pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{3pt}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{55,171,200}
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{113,200,55}
\definecolor{pool}{RGB}{85,221,255}

\begin{document}

\footnotesize\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}Sc|*4{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}}

\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text} \\
\toprule
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Text} &\cellcolor{darkblue} & \cellcolor{darkblue} & & \\
\arrayrulecolor{darkblue}\cmidrule{1-5}\noalign{\vspace*{-\cmidrulewidth}}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{4-5}
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Text} & \multirow{-3}{=}{\centering\cellcolor{darkblue}Three\\Lines\\Text} & \multirow{-3}{=}{\centering Three\\Lines\\Text}\cellcolor{darkblue} & \cellcolor{darkblue}\shortstack[c]{\bigstrut[t] Three\\Lines\\Text} & \\
\midrule
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Text} & \cellcolor{green}\shortstack[c]{\bigstrut[t] Three\\Lines\\Text} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cellcolor{pool}Single line text}\\
\midrule
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Text} & \cellcolor{darkblue} \shortstack[c]{Two Lines\\Text} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cellcolor{pool}Single line text}\\
\midrule
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Text} & \cellcolor{green}\shortstack[c]{\bigstrut[t]Three\\Lines\\Text} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cellcolor{pool}Single line text}\\
\midrule
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Text} & \cellcolor{darkblue} \shortstack[c]{two Lines\\Text} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cellcolor{pool} single line text} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]